# Problem with hash-table insertion function in C

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

I am trying to wrap my head around C right now (mostly how pointers operate).  I am trying to write this function described below:

/* EnterName      enter a Name into a symbol table. Returns a 
                  boolean indicating whether an entry for Name was 
                  already listed in the table. Passes back an argument
                   containing an entry reference for the name.

Anyway, here is the code I have written and I am not sure how to test it at the moment.  Wondering if someone could look over it and let me know if I am doing this right.

Thanks in advance.

Code::

```
bool EnterName(struct SymTab *ATable,
              const char *Name,
              struct SymEntry * *AnEntry)
{
              char name = *Name;
              unsigned hashval = hash (&name);
              struct SymEntry *ptr;

          ptr = ATable->Contents[hashval];

          while(ptr != NULL)
          {
                    if(strcmp(ptr->Name, &name)) 
                    {
                                 AnEntry = &ptr;
                                 return true;
                    } 
          }

          ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct SymEntry));
          ptr->Name = &name;
          AnEntry = &ptr;
          return false;
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you're asking us to do: compile your code for you? Write a testing harness? What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: what compiler are you using? If it is gcc then I would strongly recommend that you switch a high warning level: `-Wall`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it run and produce the results you expect?

**There's no replacement for compiling code, running it with test data, comparing results to expected values, debugging, etc, when learning a new language. Showing untested code to others and asking if it's OK isn't the right approach.**

Even the first two lines of the function don't make sense:

```
   char name = *Name;
   unsigned hashval = hash(&name);
```

You've just taken the first character of `Name` into the `name` variable, and then try to hash its address.

Now, the loop:

```
          while(ptr != NULL)
          {
                    if(strcmp(ptr->Name, &name)) 
                    {
                                 AnEntry = &ptr;
                                 return true;
                    } 
          }
```

Doesn't make sense either, since you're not advancing `ptr` anywhere - it's an infinite loop.

That said, there seems to be a step in the right direction in your code. You just have to get your types straight and fix all the rough corners. I suggest starting with small pieces - see that they compile and run, then proceed assembling into larger pieces.

Comment: It does compile, does not produce the results I would like.  

I guess that is why I am feeling overwhelmed with it.  I do not understand how pointers work.  I guess that is why I am looking for help.

Comment: @unknown: I'm not trying to preach, but sincerely to help. Read a beginner's book about C, read articles online (this is a good tutorial about pointers: http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm). There are dozens of SO questions dealing with how pointers work - you just have to look. But really start with a book/tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot at least one error. You're only hashing the first letter of each name...
name = a single chatacter (a copy)
hash(&name), hashes the copy of the single character. 
You want hash(Name), with a capital, so that you give has the beginning of the sting to hash, so it can hash the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
char name = *Name;
```

This takes the first character of `Name` and stores it in `name` (The string `Hello` would be truncated to a single `H`). You certainly want `name` to be `char*` (pointer to a array of characters) instead of a single character.

`strcmp(a,b)` returns 0 if a matches b. I think it should be

```
if(!strcmp(ptr->Name, name))
```

Also, your loop might run forever. if the first comparison fails (provided you add the !), the loop would continue forever since `ptr`'s value will never change.

There's much wrong in your code. You HAVE TO test it. Take a compiler, compile it, run it. Programming without testing is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
AnEntry = &ptr;
```

isn't doing what you want it to do. It is changing the value of the *local* variable AnEntry without changing the value in the calling routine.

You wanted

```
*AnEntry = ptr;
```

And there are several other bugs, and likely mistakes, but they seem to be reasonably well covered by others...